# /sbin/nologin and /bin/false are ignored in /etc/passwd as a user shell

Tags: ssh, opensuse, passwd

I have a following entry in `/etc/passwd` file:

```
test:x:1002:1000::/home/test:/bin/bash
```

When I change it to `test:x:1002:1000::/home/test:/bin/false` or `test:x:1002:1000::/home/test:/sbin/nologin`, then I'm still able to log in to this machine over SSH using `test` as a username. Why is this so?

Comment: It's openSUSE 11.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nscd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd) caches passwd and group information. Try `nscd -i passwd` and `nscd -i group` after directly modified those files.

Answer (score 1):

Using `/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd` file must disable user shell access. If you try to connect through ssh, it will prompt you for the password, but although you enter it, it will close the connection.

If you don't want to allow the user to login through any other way, you can use `passwd <username> -l` to block the account login.

Answer (score 0):

From the way you phrased the question, it sounds like you're modifying the passwd file manually.

Have you tried using `usermod`?  Looking over the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod), you can use `usermod -L <account>` if you just want to disable logins using the account.  If you want to change the shell use `usermod -s <shell> <account>`.

Modifying the passwd file manually is typically frowned upon as you can end up creating more problems for yourself.